# WooCommerce input select not taking default value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

With the code below, on the checkoutpage. **Santiago** is already selected which isn't what I want. I want the **default** to be on **Seleccione Destino**.

The weird thing is when I change Santiago's number from 1 to anothing else like 44 then it works correctly, it selects 0 as default. When Santiago is 1 then the default makes it Santiago.

I've also tried making the default 1287 but it still takes 1 as the default first.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_field', 20, 1 );
function add_field($billing_fields) {

    $billing_fields['billing_area'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Ubicación del Destino', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'type'          => 'select',
        'default'           => 0,
        'class'     => array('select'),
        'priority' => 65,
        'options'       => array(
            0 => 'Seleccione Ubicación',  1 => 'SANTIAGO',  1287 => 'ACHAO'
       )
    );
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```php
function add_field($billing_fields) {

    $billing_fields['billing_area'] = array(
        'label'    => __('Ubicación del Destino', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => true,
        'type'     => 'select',
        'default'  => 'seleccione_ubicación',
        'class'    => array('form-row-wide'),
        'priority' => 65,
        'options'  => array(
            'seleccione_ubicación' => 'Seleccione Ubicación',
            'santiago' => 'SANTIAGO',
            'achao' => 'ACHAO'
       )
    );

    return $billing_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_field', 10, 1 );
```